# Linq Query Multiple DataTables in DataSet

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset

Basically I have a DataSet that contains let's say 2 DataTables. The DataTables do not share a common key or field but they are related by their row index.  I have tried the following code from an MSDN example [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but because they do not share a common field I couldn't join them correctly so I tried to join using two FROM(s) to join the tables which I know is wrong.  Here is what I have:

```
public DataTable buildEmployeeDataTable(DataSet ds)
    {
        DataTable personIdentity = ds.Tables["PersonIdentity"];
        DataTable person = ds.Tables["Person"]; ;

        var query = (
            from pi in personIdentity.AsEnumerable()
            from p in person.AsEnumerable()
            select new
            {
                PersonKey = pi.Field<string>("PersonKey"),
                PersonNumber = p.Field<string>("PersonNumber"),
                FullName = p.Field<string>("FullName")
            }).ToList();

        DataTable dataTable = ConvertToDataTable(query);
        return dataTable;
    }
```

It kind of works but does this instead:

```
 PersonKey      PersonNumber     FullName
   1             42               Bob
   1             62               Jon
   1             57               Tom
   2             42               Bob
   2             62               Jon
   2             57               Tom
   3             42               Bob
   3             62               Jon
   3             57               Tom
```

Do I need to store the result in another DataTable and run SelectMany(p => p).Distinct()? What is the correct approach to join these tables so that the query returns each person by their person key? Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the two tables are ordered correctly, and that all the records match correctly, then you can just Zip them together:

```
var identities = personIdentity.AsEnumerable();
var persons = person.AsEnumerable();
var query = identities.Zip(persons, (pi, p) => new 
                                               { 
                                                   PersonKey = pi.Field<string>("PersonKey"),
                                                   PersonNumber = p.Field<string>("PersonNumber"),
                                                   FullName = p.Field<string>("FullName") 
                                               })
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: I never knew of the Zip function. Pretty cool... I found another way of accomplishing this that I will post here just for good reference but I'm marking yours as the answer.  I learned something today.  Thanks Andrew!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way I found that solved the problem I was having:

```
public DataTable buildEmployeeDataTable(DataSet ds)
    {

        DataTable personIdentity = ds.Tables["PersonIdentity"];
        DataTable person = ds.Tables["Person"]; ;

        var query = (
            from pi in personIdentity.AsEnumerable()
            join p in person.AsEnumerable() 
                on personIdentity.Rows.IndexOf(pi) equals
                person.Rows.IndexOf(p)
            select new
            {
                PersonKey = pi.Field<string>("PersonKey"),
                PersonNumber = p.Field<string>("PersonNumber"),
                FullName = p.Field<string>("FullName")
            }).ToList();

        DataTable dataTable = ConvertToDataTable(query);

        return dataTable;
    }
```

I wonder if there's any difference between this and Zip?  Thanks for the help with this!

Comment: This works, although I suspect that the Zip solution would be a little more efficient.  `Zip` basically just iterates over both sequences at the same time using the supplied lambda to produce the required result from each pair of rows.  There is no join logic to worry about.